# "keychain && ssh-add" no longer works in bionic

Tags: 18.04, ssh

Ever since moving to bionic, "keychain && ssh-add" no longer seems to work.  To be more specific, the commands seem to run without error, "ssh-add -l" even does list the keys ("keychain -l" does not), but when I use ssh to log into a remote machine, I'm still prompted to unlock the key again.  Running "eval `ssh-agent -s`" does not fix the issue. This used to work fine in trusty.

What do I need to do to get this working again?

```
$ env|grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-KhJDObLEgKkR/agent.29655
SSH_AGENT_PID=29656
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=gnome-keyring

$ ssh-add -l
1024 SHA256:nk0oSqYh6mZYedjJyMZ5ucSq1+iQXEB0+HviLgrYiBg /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa (DSA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to solve this.  It turns out, my key was too old and thus kind of disabled as a security measure, I suppose.  After creating a new key based off ED25519 and adding the corresponding public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server, things are now working again.